# Reading content text from SyndicationContent

Tags: asp.net, feed, syndicationfeed, syndication-item

Hi i am trying to read the content into string from feed items.

```
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(feedReader);    
SydicationContent itemContent = feed.Items.ToList<SyndicationItem>()[0].Content;
string retrivedContent = itemContent .......???
```

how can I read the text from the itemContent ?

The documentation shows how to create TextSyndicationContent

```
TextSyndicationContent textContent = new TextSyndicationContent("Some text content"); 

SyndicationItem item = new SyndicationItem("Item Title", textContent, new Uri("server/items";), "ItemID", DateTime.Now);
```

Any way to reverse this ?

thanks

Comment: You should consider accepting AndyH's answer rather than the given answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could take a look at [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) or at [SyndicationContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationcontent.aspx).

Comment: Thsnks any way, I am switching to argotic framework, will recommend any one stuck with SyndicaticationFeed to have a look at.

http://argotic.codeplex.com/

cheers

Answer (score 26):

```
TextSyndicationContent tsc = (TextSyndicationContent)item.Content;
string myContent = tsc.Text;
```